# How do I Loop through an Hash in a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used `group_by` to get a certain desired result. Based on the explanation in the answer, I have updated my question to reflect the answer, to see the steps it took to arrive at a solution, see the edit history.

```
@grouped_test_specific_reports = TestSpecificReport.all.group_by(&:equipment_type_name)
```

The code above produced this result:

```
    2.5.1 :026 > pp @grouped_test_specific_reports
{"Ultrasonic Probes"=>
  [#<TestSpecificReport:0x00007f832aa2d6e0
    id: 10,
    equipment_type_id: 2,
    test_method_id: 1,
    equipment_amount: "Multiple",
    equipment_heading: "UT Probes">],
 "Ultrasonic Instruments"=>
  [#<TestSpecificReport:0x00007f832aa2d3c0
    id: 8,
    equipment_type_id: 1,
    test_method_id: 1,
    equipment_amount: "Single",
    equipment_heading: "UT Instrument">],
 "Visual Test Equipment"=>
  [#<TestSpecificReport:0x00007f832aa2cfb0
    id: 11,
    equipment_type_id: 4,
    test_method_id: 1,
    equipment_amount: "Single",
    equipment_heading: "VT Equipment">]}
 => {"Ultrasonic Probes"=>[#<TestSpecificReport id: 10, equipment_type_id: 2, test_method_id: 1, equipment_amount: "Multiple", equipment_heading: "UT Probes">], "Ultrasonic Instruments"=>[#<TestSpecificReport id: 8, equipment_type_id: 1, test_method_id: 1, equipment_amount: "Single", equipment_heading: "UT Instrument">], "Visual Test Equipment"=>[#<TestSpecificReport id: 11, equipment_type_id: 4, test_method_id: 1, equipment_amount: "Single", equipment_heading: "VT Equipment">]}
```

My next goal is to list out the grouped test specific report in the browser by their keys, I was able to do that by `@grouped_test_specific_reports.each { |key, value| puts key }`

- "Visual Test Equipment"
- "Ultrasonic Instruments" and
- "Ultrasonic Probes"

Now we have to iterate over the values, which happens to be an array, in another loop to be able to compare `equipment_amount`.

The values with `equipment_amount: "Multiple"` will have the plus icon in front of them, and the ones with `equipment_amount: "Single"` will simply be a drop-down:

Here's the code for the UI:

```
- @grouped_test_specific_reports.each do |equipment_type_name, test_specific_reports|
  .form-group.row
    .col-sm-6
      %label
        = equipment_type_name
      = select_tag '', options_from_collection_for_select(test_specific_reports, :id, :equipment_heading), { include_blank: "Select #{equipment_type_name} List", class: 'form-control select2', style: 'width: 100%;' }
    .col-sm-1
      - test_specific_reports.each do |test_specific_report|
        - if test_specific_report.equipment_amount == 'Multiple'
          .icon.text-center
            %i.fa.fa-plus-circle.add-icon
```

Comment: I'm not clear... if you have two "Ultrasonic Probes" and only one is "multiple" do you want the Plus icon to appear next to the whole selector, or just next to the specific drop down entry that has "multiple"?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 "Ultrasonic Probes" and 2 "Ultrasonic Instruments" that both have Multiple and Single equipment_amount, but I only want the plus icon to appear next to Ultrasonic Probes, that has Multiple equipment_amount and Ultrasonic Instruments that have multiple equipment_amount.

Comment: So the plus icon before the drop down should only appear if an item with "Multiple" is selected? If you change the selection to an item of type "Single" the plus should disappear? What happens when you click the plus icon? Is another select element created that only contains items in the same group that have "Multiple"? What should happen when an item with "Multiple" is selected, the plus icon is clicked and then the value is changed back to one that has "Single"?

Comment: Thanks, @JohanWentholt very good questions, yes, the plus should only appear when an item with Multiple is selected. If the selected item is changed from an item with a type of Multiple to a type of Single the plus icon should disappear. When the Plus Icon is clicked, an item is created and inserted into a join table between the current model "Report" and the "Equipment" table. After Plus icon is clicked the field should go back to the default value "Ultrasonic Probe List" for example.

Comment: I personally think there might be something wrong with the design. You might want to give the groups their own model/table, since this seems like an attribute that should be set on the group instead. Alternatively (while still using a group model) you might want to specify a certain amount of inventory slots a group has. Each selectable item takes up *X* amount of slots. Then set up a validation to make sure that the sum of inventory slots of the selected items take op less or equal the amount of inventory slots a the group has.

Comment: I've got one last follow-up question. So assume you've selected an item that is of type "Multiple". You clicked the plus icon and it's added to the table. Should the select element still contain the values with type "Single", or should they be removed from the selectable values? Since I assume you can't select an item of type "Single" if there is already an item added to the table. Along the same lines, should those options (with type "Single") return into the selectable elements if the last element is deleted from the table?

Comment: So I clarified with the client, he said an Equipment should not have Multiple and Single values at the same time, I have edited my question above to reflect this, so basically, only one item has Multiple and only that should have the plus icon next to it. 
My only issue here is, how do i loop through the value to check if an equipment_amount is multiple or single?
I plan to use ajax to Add the item to the join table and list them beneath according to the design, that's actually the mockup that was sent to me.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the design, I basically misunderstood it and your questions forced me to clarify that. Thanks. Since the items are grouped by equipment name, if an item has multiple equipment amount with the plus icon, it means that it could be added multiple times to the table. Check the design for the table with title "Ultrasonic Probes added to report" that's where the items will be added when plus icon is clicked.

Comment: The looping is simple. First you have to realize that the value is an array, so not really a value, but rather values. You can loop through them with any of the [*Array*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html) and [*Enumerable*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html) methods. For example: `values.each { |value| ... }`, or `singles, multiples = values.partition { |value| value.equipment_amount == 'Single' }`.

Comment: Thanks but what is the meaning of partition?

Comment: Splitting up the collection into two groups. Values for which the block returns a truethy value, and values for which the block returns a falsey value. Have a look at the documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition

Comment: did it like this and it worked. I'll update the question. But I wish to explore partition further, thanks.

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid having to loop twice, I thought there might be a better solution, looping twice is what we ended up doing. At least it works now, exactly like in the design. Next is to create the join tables and use ajax to create the multiple and insert in the table below

Comment: You also might want to consider using [`options_from_collection_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) instead of [`options_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select). `options_from_collection_for_select` allows you to select a method that is used for the display name, and a method that is used for the value. Making it more readable than `#<SomeObject with_some_attributes: "and values">`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually changed to using f.collection_select, the f as in form is fake because this value does not get inserted into the current model of the form, so I know it's not gonna work by the time I'm done. I'll take a look at `options_from_collection_for_select` as well. Thanks for your time. I might still come back with questions once I starting working on the join table.

Comment: You can't avoid looping twice, since you first time you loop through the groups and the second time you loop through the values of the group. Those are two different things so you have to do it that way. It is possible to do it in one single loop, but it involves not grouping them in the first place. Instead separate them out using if statements or cases. However this will clutter up your code like crazy so I don't recommend it. Might you have any other issues consider creating a new question instead. Try to isolate out the issue you're having and describe what you expect the code to do.

Comment: You are right. That clarifies everything. I will create a new question if necessary and send a link here. Thanks. Please, drop your comment above as the answer with loop code so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you @JohanWentholt 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally found the question you're asking a bit unclear. For this reason I discussed some things in the comments with you. From our discussion in the comments it seemed you simply wanted to loop through the grouped values for each group.

First I want to clear up what [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) exactly does, because this seemed to be the issue. A simple misunderstanding of what you're currently working on.

> #### group_by { |obj| block } → a_hash
>
> #### group_by → an_enumerator
>
> Groups the collection by result of the block. Returns a hash where the keys are the evaluated result from the block and the values are arrays of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.
>
> If no block is given an enumerator is returned.
>
> ```
> (1..6).group_by { |i| i%3 }   #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
> ```

The documentation makes clear that the grouped hash has keys that evaluate from the block (the return value). The value that belongs to the key is actually an list of values that evaluate to the same result. This means you can simply loop through the values in the following way.

```
grouped_values = (1..6).group_by { |n| n % 3 }

grouped_values.each do |key, values|
  puts "Key: #{key}"

  values.each do |value|
    puts "Value: #{value}"
  end
end
```

The first `each` loops through the groups. The second `each` loops through the values of the group. Since you loop though two different things you can't change this into a single loop easily. The important thing to remember here that the value belonging to a group key is not a single value, but rather a group of values (array).